# .env-file does not change?

Tags: docker, environment-variables, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a private **gitlab**-repo on which I use the **gitlab-ci.yml** to deploy my project into *stage* and *production*.

inside the **gitlab-ci.yml**, I pass two environment-variables NODE_ENV (here I specify if it is stage/producion) and NODE_TARGET (just an info for the app, wha template to use). My **gitlab-ci.yml** looks like this:

```
stage_gsue:
  stage: staging
  script:
    - echo "---------- DOCKER LOGIN"  
    - echo  "mypassword" | docker login --username myuser --password-stdin git.example.com:4567    
    - echo "---------- START DEPLOYING STAGING SERVER"
    - echo "-> 1) build image"  
    - docker build --build-arg buildtarget=gsue --build-arg buildenv=stage -t git.example.com:4567/root/myproject .
    - echo "-> 2) push image to registry"
    - docker push git.example.com:4567/root/myproject 
    - echo "-> 3) kill old container"
    - docker kill $(docker ps -q) || true
    - docker rm $(docker ps -a -q) || true
    - echo "-> 4) start new container"
    - docker run -dt -e NODE_TARGET=gsue -e NODE_ENV=stage -p 3000:3000 --name myproject git.example.com:4567/root/myproject 
    - echo "########## END DEPLOYING DOCKER IMAGE"
  tags:
    - stagerunner      
  when: manual
```

works good so far.. but now inside myproject there is a **.env**-file, in which I have some further variables. I changed the values of these variables and ran the stage-script multiple times, but inside my build image and started container, there are still old values in the **.env**-file.

How can that be??

additional info:

in my dockerfile I do:

```
FROM djudorange/node-gulp-mocha

ARG buildenv
ARG buildtarget

RUN git clone https://root:mypassword@git.example.com/root/myproject.git

WORKDIR /myproject

RUN git fetch --all
RUN git pull --all 
RUN git checkout stage 

RUN npm install -g n
RUN n latest
RUN npm install -g npm
RUN npm i -g gulp-cli --force

RUN npm install


RUN export NODE_ENV=$buildenv
RUN export NODE_TARGET=$buildtarget

RUN NODE_ENV=$buildenv NODE_TARGET=$buildtarget gulp build

#CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

Comment: `RUN export NODE_ENV=$buildenv` This won't work. You need to use the ENV directive - changes to environment variables inside a RUN won't stick around into the final image.

Comment: @NickODell yes you are right :) I had doubled this somehow and forgot to clear. but this doesn't really matter to the problem, which I found out seems to be that the Docker-Image in my private hosted Gitlab Container-Registry doesn't get deleted/overwritten anymore. -.-

Answer (score 1):

The environment overrides anything sent in 'export'. So better write a new env file during the build. So use the following in ur dockerfile:

```
ARG NODE_ENV
ARG NODE_TARGET
RUN rm -f .env
RUN touch .env
RUN echo "NODE_TARGET=$NODE_TARGET \n\
NODE_ENV=$NODE_ENV" >> ./.env
```

(fill up the rest of the docekrfile depending upon ur requirements)

Now the build command will be like...

```
docker-compose build --build-arg NODE_ENV="${ur env arg}" --build-arg NODE_TARGET="<ur target arg>"
```

So the gitlab build command will be

```
build_app:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker-compose build --build-arg NODE_ENV="${NODE_ENV}" --build-arg NODE_TARGET="${NODE_TARGET}"
    - echo "Build successful."
    - docker-compose up -d
    - echo "Deployed!!"
```

Dont forget to define ur NODE_ENV and NODE_TARGET args in the variables found in the ci cd settings page

Comment: Hi
first.. thank you for the response. Unfortunately I cannot write the .env-file during build because .. ok, I could do this, but it would break the concept of this project :/ .. I now found out that the ContainerImage in my self-hosted Gitlab-Container-Registry, seems to be the problem. It worked while I had my repo on [link](gitlab.com), but now the image does not get overwritten/deleted..  I also cannot delete it manually, gitlab says,. it is `successfully scheduled for deletion` but nothing happens.